# My custom attribute not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to make an attribute so that I can decorate an action/controller and have some code run.

This is the code for my Attribute:

```
public class UpdateLastLogInAttribute   : System.Attribute
{
    Linq.UserMinData umd { get; set; }    
    public UpdateLastLogInAttribute()
    {
        this.umd =datafuncs.GetMinData();
        if (umd != null)
            datafuncs.SaveLastConnected(umd);
    }                 
}
```

...and this is the Controller that I want the Attribute to work with

```
[funcs.UpdateLastLogIn]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

However, when I hit the controller, my code never executes. What's wrong?

Comment: "not working" isn't a description of a problem.

Comment: You've shown us some code, but you haven't told us what you're trying to achieve, or what actually happens. "It's not working" is not a useful description of the problem.

Comment: My custom attribute dont execute

Answer (score 2):

Attributes are dumb. There isn't any magic that makes code in attributes run. It's down to you to reflect on your code and to detect the attributes and run the code.

Fortunately, MVC already does this for specific attribute types, so...

You might consider extending [`ActionFilterAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and overriding [`OnActionExecuting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx),[`OnActionExecuted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuted(v=vs.118).aspx), [`OnResultExecuting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onresultexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx) or [`OnResultExecuted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onresultexecuted(v=vs.118).aspx) depending on which phase of the request you want to intercept.

MVC looks out for subclasses of this attribute and executes the four methods above at the appropriate time.

Comment: i did OnResultExecuting, but i see that the attribute run couple of times insted of one , why is that?

Comment: That's a new question. Provide code. Make sure you explain what's going wrong. Look at the changes I made to your question to make it useful.